# Authentication on Laravel microservices architecture

Tags: laravel, authentication, microservices

I am trying to implement API bearer authentication across my micro services using Laravel.

I followed the following tutorial [Laravel Rest API Authentication](https://fajarwz.com/blog/laravel-rest-api-authentication-using-jwt-tutorial/) however it only works on one API. It also used JWT. My requirements are not limited to JWT, I am open to anything.

So just for context, I have a users service which is the one that does the authentication to make sure that the username and password supplied is correct. This works and I get a token back. Now I would like to use the same token to authenticate the books api to be able to get the books section as the endpoint is supposed to be protected.

I also need to highlight that each service has its own database.

Is what am trying to achieve possible? If so, can anyone point me perhaps to a tutorial I can follow to achieve this?